# Remove "Mass Email" from Standard profile?

Tags: profile, mass-email

"Mass Email"is a system property in standard profiles. Is there any way to prevent selected standard profiles to send mass mails?

Permission set can allow for selected users to send mass mails. I'm unable to find a way to set this property for profile.

Is customization imminent?

Comment: Yes, You can't make changes in standard profiles.With permission set also you can only provide permission.You can not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the Standard Profile and then make the adjustments in your clone. You can then assign this to users in lieu of the Standard Profile.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As I explained in my question, standard profiles are needed to be removed from it's ability to send mass email. I guess it's not possible.

Comment: As Mr.Frodo said, you cannot change Standard Profiles. Is there a reason why you must use a Standard profile as opposed to a custom profile cloned from the Standard?